# Camera.MAUI barcode detection not working with absolute layout or grid but works with scroll view vertical layout

Tags: camera, maui, barcode-scanner

I am trying to use absolute layout or grid * to make it so my camera view takes up the whole screen no matter what device youre using but when i do the barcode isnt being detected. before i was using scrollview and vertical stack layout and it was, i even re did it to make sure it was because of that.

`these are the two examples of what i was trying to do:

using absolute layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:cv="clr-namespace:Camera.MAUI;assembly=Camera.MAUI"
             x:Class="J2MobilePClock.CameraPage">

    <ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
        <ToolbarItem Order="Secondary" Text="Punch in" Clicked="BtnMainPage_Clicked"/>
    </ContentPage.ToolbarItems>

    <AbsoluteLayout>
        <cv:CameraView x:Name="cameraView" IsVisible="True"
            CamerasLoaded="cameraView_CamerasLoaded" BarCodeDetectionEnabled="True"
            BarcodeDetected="cameraView_BarcodeDetected"
            AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All"
            AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0,0,1,1"/>

    </AbsoluteLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

using grid:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:cv="clr-namespace:Camera.MAUI;assembly=Camera.MAUI"
             x:Class="J2MobilePClock.CameraPage">

    <ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
        <ToolbarItem Order="Secondary" Text="Punch in" Clicked="BtnMainPage_Clicked"/>
    </ContentPage.ToolbarItems>

    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <cv:CameraView x:Name="cameraView" IsVisible="True"
            CamerasLoaded="cameraView_CamerasLoaded" BarCodeDetectionEnabled="True"
            BarcodeDetected="cameraView_BarcodeDetected"/>
    </Grid>
</ContentPage>
```

I was expecting it to just work since other the height and width the camera view was not edited at all.
this is what i had before when it was working:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:cv="clr-namespace:Camera.MAUI;assembly=Camera.MAUI"
             x:Class="J2MobilePClock.CameraPage">

    <ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
        <ToolbarItem
          Order="Secondary"
          Text="Punch in" 
          Clicked="BtnMainPage_Clicked"/>

    </ContentPage.ToolbarItems>

    <ScrollView>
        <VerticalStackLayout
            Spacing="25"
            Padding="30,0"
            VerticalOptions="Center">

            <cv:CameraView x:Name="cameraView" WidthRequest="600" HeightRequest="800" IsVisible="True"
                CamerasLoaded="cameraView_CamerasLoaded" BarCodeDetectionEnabled="True"
                BarcodeDetected="cameraView_BarcodeDetected"/>

        </VerticalStackLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</ContentPage>
```

Answer (score 0):

> My camera view takes up the whole screen no matter what device you're
> using.

You need to add  `HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"` and `VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"` of the `CameraView` to make it full screen and then scan the barcode or QR code.

Here's the code below for your reference:

**XAML:**

```
<Grid>       
         <cv:CameraView x:Name="cameraView"  
                           HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                           VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                           CamerasLoaded="cameraView_CamerasLoaded"
                           BarCodeDetectionEnabled="True"                                              
  BarcodeDetected="cameraView_BarcodeDetected"/>

 </Grid>
```

**Code-behind:**

```
 private void cameraView_CamerasLoaded(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
        if (cameraView.Cameras.Count > 0)
        {
              cameraView.Camera = cameraView.Cameras.First();
              MainThread.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(async () =>
              {
                    await cameraView.StopCameraAsync();
                    await cameraView.StartCameraAsync();
               });
         }
 }

 private void cameraView_BarcodeDetected(object sender, Camera.MAUI.ZXingHelper.BarcodeEventArgs args)
  {
        MainThread.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
        {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(args.Result[0]);
        });
  }
```